# C#, Thread, Memory

Tags: c#, multithreading, memory

Today I would like to know how to save an image to Stream (really in memory it's possible that I don't use the appropriate term) and read it from another Thread.

To do this I think to proceed with these steps :
A - In first Thread :
    1 - Create Image object (System.Drawing) from file
    2 - Create thumbnail
    3 - Save thumbnail to Stream (System.IO)
    4 - Send Stream object to second Thread.

B - In second Thread :
    1 - Receive Stream from first Thread
    2 - Create BitmapImage object with this Stream
    3 - Displaying on UI. (Wpf)

Thks.

Comment: If what T2 receives is same memory as what T1 sends, saving and reading needs a common lock object so they don't happen at the same time.

Comment: Why you want use stream? A) 1 - Create Image object; 2. Send object to the second thread. B) 1. Receive image object; 2. Displaying on UI. (Wpf)

Comment: @Fabio I've tried this, but I failed to do this because I've could not use the object sended by T2. If you have a example to explain me how to do this, you can show me.

Comment: Can you show the code - how you send stream from thread1 to thread2?

Comment: Sorry but I've erase the code.

Comment: @Fabio But if you have a simple example I can to do what I want with it. For your information I've doesn't used Lock to do this (To pass a stream between Thread).

Answer (score 0):

I've retrieve a part of my code I show you what I did :

In the Thread that check my images in some folders :

```
public void CreateImgObj(object sender)
{
    try
    {
        FileStream fs = File.Open((string)sender, FileMode.Open);
        Bitmap dImg = new Bitmap(fs);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        dImg.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        BitmapImage bi_img = new BitmapImage();
        bi_img.BeginInit();
        bi_img.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray());
        bi_img.EndInit();
        evt_send_img(bi_img);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        evt_error(e);
    }
}
```

In the UI Thread :

```
    private void img_recieve(object sender)
    {
        try
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
                 {
                     items.Add(new Img { Img_In = (BitmapImage)sender });
                 }));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            messageerreur(e);
        }
    }
```

Note : "img_recieve" is execute by "evt_send_img";

Thks

Comment: Please don't ever code `catch (Exception e)` unless you're trying to hide bugs.